# Openpyxl 2.4.1 can't get rid of green arrows in Excel after setting new number_format

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I am trying to get rid of green arrows in Excel standing for:
'The number in this cell is formatted as text or preceded by an apostrophe.'

Working with Openpyxl 2.4.1 and Python 3.5.2.

For now function looks like this (however I have tried many different versions):

```
def price():
    cena = input("Cena: ")
    cena = cena.replace('.', ',')
    cell = 'D' + str(row)
    arkusz1.active[cell].number_format = '0.00'
    arkusz1.active[cell] = cena
    print("Wprowadzono Cenę. \n")
```

After this there is indeed cell with number format in excel
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HJaT1.jpg)

but the green arrow is still present and the value's format isn't a number - can't be used in formulae.

Any solution?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the cell contains a string in which case the number format doesn't matter. The green arrows are there because Excel thinks the string should be converted to a number. To avoid this you should handle the conversion yourself: `cena = float(cena)`

Comment: That was my first thought but the problem is that I want to replace dots with commas for excel's purposes.
When I convert it to float I get:
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '9983,1'

Comment: You'll still need to that first, obviously. Though I think you can also use the `locale` module.

Comment: Someone help me with totally another solution, but it was quite long. Fortunately I have noticed that the simplest solution was to add new variable like this: cena_nowa = float(cena) and now it works as expected.

Comment: That is exactly what I suggested. Whatever.